# How to get distinct sets of rows using SQL (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation where I need to work with EAV data in an existing application where refactoring is not an option, so I can't change the structure of the data. That said, I have a query that returns data like so

```
| account | field | value | group |
|---------|-------|-------|-------|
| 1       | A     | 1     | 1     |
| 1       | B     | foo   | 1     |
| 1       | A     | 2     | 2     |
| 1       | B     | foo   | 2     |
| 1       | A     | 2     | 3     |
| 1       | B     | foo   | 3     |
| 2       | A     | 1     | 4     |
| 2       | A     | 2     | 5     |
| 2       | A     | 1     | 6     |
```

How can I remove groups 3 and 6, based on the fact that groups 2 and 4 have all of the same accounts, fields, and values respectively?

I thought of using something like

```
select account, field, value, rank() over (partition by account, field, value order by group)
```

but the members of the group will have different rankings depending on whether each specific row has been seen before.

In other words, is it possible to get a distinct "sets" of rows, eliminating others with the same number of rows and the same value for those rows, using the "group" column, where the number of rows in different groups may be different?

EDIT:

I'm not sure the original example was a very good one. Using distinct/unique will not work, as I'm interested in distinct groups of rows, not distinct rows. As a better example, consider

```
| account | field | value | group |
|---------|-------|-------|-------|
| 1       | A     | 1     | 1     |
| 1       | B     | foo   | 1     |
| 1       | A     | 1     | 2     |
| 1       | B     | bar   | 2     |
| 1       | A     | 2     | 3     |
| 1       | B     | foo   | 3     |
| 2       | A     | 1     | 4     |
| 2       | A     | 2     | 5     |
| 2       | A     | 1     | 6     |
| 3       | A     | 1     | 7     |
| 3       | B     | foo   | 7     |
| 3       | C     | bar   | 7     |
| 3       | A     | 1     | 8     |
| 3       | B     | foo   | 8     |
| 3       | C     | baz   | 8     |
| 3       | A     | 1     | 9     |
| 3       | B     | foo   | 9     |
| 3       | C     | bar   | 9     |
```

In this case, I I would like to remove only groups 6 and 9, as they are the same as groups 4 and 7, respectively. I still need to keep all of the information about the other groups, including the fact that they are grouped.

Comment: What if you have a group that is a subset of another? eg. (3, A, 1, 7) and (3, A, 1, 8) (3, B, boo, 8) ? Which rows should be shown in this case?

Comment: @Boneist -- All of these groups should be shown. I only want to remove groups that have exactly the same number of and entries for account, field, and value. The specific value of group isn't important, only that rows with the same group number form a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using part of the suggestion by @Hogan

```
WITH hashes AS
(SELECT group,
        SUM(Ora_hash(Concat(Concat(account,field), value))) AS hash
 FROM table
 GROUP BY group)
SELECT account,
       field,
       value,
       group
FROM table
WHERE group IN (SELECT group
                FROM (SELECT group,
                             row_number() over (PARTITION BY hash ORDER BY NULL) AS rn
                      FROM hashes)
                WHERE  rn = 1);
```

The downside to this is that I believe there will be issues if the length of the concatenation of fields passed to ora_hash() surpasses the maximum character length for a varchar2 field. Ora_hash() is NOT deterministic for LOB fields, so casting to CLOB would not help. In my case, length constraints on the account, field, and value columns in the database will prevent this from occuring. In other cases, it may be useful to look into the dbms_crypto.hash() function.

EDIT:

It seems the ora_hash() function has an unacceptably high rate of collisions for this type of problem. Considering that I am already relying on the fact that the concatenations will not pass the varcar2 character limit, it may be better to compare the values directly. This will only fail in the case that the concatentation of two distinct fields yields the same result, e.g. ('a', 'bc') and ('ab', 'c'), as opposed to the possibility for collisions of any values with ora_hash().

```
WITH group_vals AS
(SELECT group,
        listagg(account || field || value, ',') AS vals
 FROM table
 GROUP BY group)
SELECT account,
       field,
       value,
       group
FROM table
WHERE group IN (SELECT group
                FROM (SELECT group,
                             row_number() over (PARTITION BY vals ORDER BY NULL) AS rn
                      FROM group_vals)
                WHERE  rn = 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

New answer based on comments:

```
WITH Prior AS
(
  -- First find matches to Prior groups
  SELECT A.account, A.field, A.value, A.group, MIN(B.group) as Prior_Group
  FROM TABLE A
  LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.account=B.account 
                   AND A.Field = B.field
                   AND A.value = B.value
                   AND A.group > B.group
  GROUP BY A.account, A.field, A.value, A.group
), Counts AS 
(
  -- Count group members and priors
  -- Using a trick that nulls for Prior_Group won't be counted
  SELECT account, field, value, group, 
         Count(*) AS Group_Count, Count(Prior_Group) as Prior_Count
  FROM Prior 
  GROUP BY account, field, value, group
)
SELECT account, field, value, group
FROM TABLE
WHERE (account, field, value, group) NOT IN 
  (SELECT account, field, value, group
   FROM Counts 
   WHERE Group_Count = Prior_Count)
```

---

You can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT account, field, value 
FROM (
   -- PRIOR QUERY
) x
```

or

```
SELECT account, field, value 
FROM (
   -- PRIOR QUERY
) x
GROUP BY account, field, value
```

Finally if you want to include the "lowest group" in the distinct set you can do this

```
SELECT account, field, value, group
FROM (
  SELECT account, field, value, group
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY account, field, value ORDER BY group ASC) AS rn
  FROM (
     -- PRIOR QUERY
  ) x
) x2
WHERE rn = 1
```

a side note, using the row_number() trick, you can include any other columns you want without worry if they are part of the distinct partition.

Comment: The first two examples will not work, as they deal with each row individually, and I need to consider groups of rows. The third example will also not work, because row_number() does not consider the grouping. If the first grouping has any field and value the same as the first, it will have a row_number() > 1, and be removed. I need to keep entire groups intact.

Comment: No idea what you mean by keep entire groups intact.  You must specify your requirements more rigorously

Comment: Above, I meant to say if the second grouping has any account, field, and value the same as the first. For example (3, A, 1) in groups 7 and 8 above. I need to retain both of these rows since they are in different groups, and the groups are not equal when considering all elements.  Namely, (3, C, bar) and (3, C, baz) are not equal.

Comment: @A.Hill -   You only want to exclude groups where all of that group's tuples (account, field, value) exists in a lower numbered group?  If any of the group's tuples don't exist all of its rows stay in?

Comment: This also does not work. While closer, using the count to determine duplicates is not reliable, because if there are groups that contain values seen before in other, separate groups, there will be values for the prior_group that are distinct, but not null, and the count will be the same, thus removing valid entries. Your previous mention of using row_number() gave me an idea though, and I have solved the problem. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, this is what you are looking for.

```
select distinct account, field, value from table
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. This will give distinct rows. I need distinct groups of rows, based on groups formed by the group column. This will distinct single rows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but this seems like it would be a simple group by and min aggregation.  Assuming you always want to return the minimum group # when duplicate account, field and values exist.

```
SELECT account, field, value, min(group) as group
FROM  table
GROUP BY account, field, value
```

Comment: This will not work. I'm not sure my original example was clear enough. I have added a more detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach but using LISTAGG instead of SUM and ora_hash (if you are on 11g R2 or above):

```
WITH lists AS
  (SELECT account, field, "value", "group", LISTAGG(account||field||"value", '-')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY account, field, "value") OVER (PARTITION BY "group") AS list
    FROM test
  )
SELECT account, field, "value", "group"
FROM lists
WHERE "group" IN
  (SELECT "group"
    FROM
      (SELECT "group", row_number() over (partition BY list order by "group") AS rn
        FROM lists)
    WHERE rn = 1
  )
ORDER BY "group", account, field, "value";
```